# How do I get the ip address via a bash script?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have an application that requires you to input your ip address as a parameter, how to do I use a bash script to automatically get the ip address and have it put it in as a parameter for the program?

Comment: [so] duplicate [Putting IP Address into bash variable. Is there a better way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6829605)

Comment: Have you thought of using localhost as the ip?  Or do you have to give it a specific ip address?  Because if it's running on my computer, localhost will work for just my computer, or whichever computer it's running on.

Comment: hmm, I just want it to get the ip address of wlan0, not the loopback ip address. dakre18, the progarm is  a simple network sniffer, and I want the ip address it uses to be my own ip address. Having it sniff the loopback is pointless

Comment: you could always create a host file entry for any arbitrary name, to map it to your wlan0 IP, but if you really want to programatically define it, please check the SO threads DavidPostill linked.

Comment: The following works on Ubuntu: `ifconfig wlan0|grep inet\ addr|sed -e 's/^.*inet addr://' -e 's/ Bcast:.*$//'`. If it doesn't work for you, examine the output of `ifconfig wlan0` and change the search fields accordingly. If you need it in a variable, use `ip=$(AboveExpression)`.

Comment: If instead you want your public ip [Command for determining my public IP?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip)...  If it works e.g `hostname -I` you can use `./myApp  --IP $(hostname -I)` if `--IP` is the option to give to your program before the IP. Choose a GNU independent solution and use it...

Answer (score 2):

Note that this can output multiple addresses, because "*the* address" hasn't necessarily been true for many years now.

### Linux

Using iproute2 and awk:

```
ip addr show scope global | awk '$1 ~ /^inet/ {print $2}'
ip -4 addr show scope global | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}'
ip -6 addr show scope global | awk '$1 == "inet6" {print $2}'
```

Using iproute2's recent JSON support:

```
ip -json addr show scope global | jq -r '.[] | .addr_info | .[] | .local'
ip -json -4 addr show scope global | jq -r '.[] | .addr_info | .[] | .local'
ip -json -6 addr show scope global | jq -r '.[] | .addr_info | .[] | .local'

ip -json addr | jq -r '.[] | .addr_info | .[] | select(.scope == "global") | .local'
ip -json addr | jq -r '.[] | .addr_info | .[] | select(.family == "inet" and .scope == "global") | .local'
ip -json addr | jq -r '.[] | .addr_info | .[] | select(.family == "inet6" and .scope == "global") | .local'
```

### FreeBSD

Using FreeBSD ifconfig and awk (filtering by scope is a bit more difficult here):

```
ifconfig -a | awk '$1 ~ /^inet/ {print $2}'
ifconfig -a | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}'
```

Also note that *ifconfig* has many different output styles between different OSes – even Linux has at least three versions.

Comment: Works fine on CentOS 7—seems like best answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Or just:

```
ipaddr=$(ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/inet addr:/ {gsub("addr:","",$2); print $2}')
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? Your answer is at risk of being removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can install [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) then use [`ifdata`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ifdata):

> `ifdata` - get network interface info without parsing `ifconfig` output
>
> […]
>
> `-pa`
> Prints the IPv4 address of the interface.

Example:

```
ifdata -pa wlan0            # print the address
ipaddr=$(ifdata -pa wlan0)  # assign to variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out the answer after looking up the answer to "Putting IP Address into bash variable. Is there a better way."

It simply requires a small tweak where instead of ifconfig, its ifconfig wlan0. Then I got had to use a backtick to plug it into a variable.

So I managed to get to work with the code

```
ipAddr = "$(ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
./myApp $ipAddr
```