# How to remove string after matched word in bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to delete string after matched word in bash.

Suppose:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet-12 HWaddr 94:EE:88:00:FA:AA
```

I want to remove `encap:Ethernet-12` from this line.

It should become like `eth0 Link HWaddr 94:EE:88:00:FA:AA`.
How to achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Consider asking about getting the information (name & MAC address) instead of focusing on just one specific method to do so...

Comment: In case it's [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) -- maybe  [`ifdata`](https://superuser.com/a/1312347/432690) is (a part of) what you need.

Comment: Consider this as "id=1235, name=first_second_name  job-title=Manager" Salary=123. If in this I want to delete job-title=Manager. It is a bash script and was looking for solution in sed/awk.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r 's/(eth0 Link )[^ ]+ /\1/'
```

In slo-mo:

- match `eth0 Link` (with final space) and keep it
- match any consecutive non-space (so, next word)
- match an additional space
- replace the lot by the string kept in the first match

  ```
  ~>echo "eth0 Link encap:Ethernet-12 HWaddr 94:EE:88:00:FA:AA" | sed -r 's/(eth0 Link )[^ ]+ /\1/'                                    
  eth0 Link HWaddr 94:EE:88:00:FA:AA
  ```

---

> is it possible to do it with searching `encap` and then replacing string after it till space?

Yes. This filter

```
sed -r 's/encap[^ ]+ //'
```

will replace the `encap` part (trailing space included) with literally nothing, effectively removing it.

Comment: I have just improved formatting of the question. There are multiple spaces after `eth0` (ill format used to hide them). You may want to adjust your answer.

Comment: thanks @xenoid . But is it possible to do it with searching encap and then replacing string after it till space.
I mean right you are searching "eth0 LInk" and then after this replacing value. It will be better to use which search with encap. I am not sure if that is possible with sed.

Comment: @user2761565 I added to xenoid's answer to address your comment, because there's no point in keeping you waiting. I could have written my own answer but it wouldn't be fair. I'm sure if you made your conditions clear from the very beginning, xenoid would have solved it in the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
after searching a lot found one silly solution.
replace space with newline and again replace newline with space. Sorry for such bad solution but if we know space is separator, we can use it.

   #var=`echo "eth0 Link encap:Ethernet-12 HWaddr 94:EE:88:00:FA:AA" | tr " " "\n" | egrep -v "encap" | tr "\n" " "`
    #echo $var
    eth0 Link HWaddr 94:EE:88:00:FA:AA
```

I know sed is right way but I am not getting how to achive it. In my case I can take space as separator.